# Enemy's parts are visible through the walls in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a location consisting of several connected rooms and some enemies chasing me. But when bots are walking very close to walls I can see their hands passing through the walls, despite both bots and walls have colliders and enemies cannot go through them. Is there any way I can create a border or something to prevent it?

Comment: increase collider size to be sure that arms doesn't overcome them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like @Heisenbug is probably correct.

I would attach a secondary collider to your model, most likely a box (for speedy processing) and call it `personal_space`. This way you can control how much space they give themselves from walls and such while still allowing them to get closer to the player and other special objects.